# javascript reload specific page onorientationchange does not work

Tags: orientation-changes

I need to reload a specific page for users when the orientation is changed.

The url is https://www.sitename/checkout/payment

I was thinking something like the below will work, but it doesnt...

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("/checkout/payment") >= 0){ 
      window.onorientationchange = function()
      {     
         window.location.reload();
      };
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is your Code, first you have to add a semicolon ";"